# Catch bounds_changed event when user moves the map but not the setCenter method

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to listen 'bounds_changed' event when the user moves the map, changes the zoom but I don't want it to be fired when my program calls setCenter or setZoom methods. So I tried removing event before setting center and adding it after, again. However, it didn't worked, My event is still being fired.

```
var currentBoundsListener = null;

function addBoundsChangedListener() {
    currentBoundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
        // Whatever.
    });
}

function setCenter(lat, lng) {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(currentBoundsListener);
    var geo = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.setCenter(geo);
    addBoundsChangedListener();
}
```

I think the map is creating bounds_changed event after I add the new listener to it, like the event is asynchronised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bounds_changed event is indeed fired asynchronously so, instead of removing the listener you could use a global boolean variable that indicates when to ignore it, for example:

```
var ignore = false; // this var is global;
currentBoundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
if(ignore) {
   ignore = false;
   return;
}

// Whatever.
});


function setCenter(lat, lng) {
    var geo = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    ignore = true;
    map.setCenter(geo);
}
```

Comment: so where I will make ignore = false again? if I do it after map.setCenter(geo), it won't work too.